# Strict object mapping in Redux and Typescript

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I have a state in a redux slice that looks like this:

```
interface MyState {
  key1: string,
  key2: boolean,
  key3: number,
}
```

I have an action called `set` that looks like this:

```
set: (state: MyState, action: PayloadAction<{key: keyof MyState, value: any}>) => {
  const { key, value } = action.payload;
  state[key] = value;
},
```

I want to strictly enforce the keys and values of the `set()` action to check the type of the specific key. example:

```
set('key1', 1); // -> error: key1 must be a string
set('key1', 'my string value'); // -> no error

set('key2', boolean); // -> no error
set('key2', 'my string value'); // -> error: must be a boolean
```

I found this function signature definition, but I don't know how to apply it inside of a `PayloadAction<any>` type to extend the current redux action payload type

```
function setAttribute<T extends Object, U extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: U, value: T[U]) {
    obj[key] = value;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this, using an intermediate mapped object:

```
interface MyState {
  foo: string
  bar: number
  baz: boolean
}

type MyStatePayloads = { 
    [Key in keyof MyState]: { key: Key, value: MyState[Key] } 
}[keyof MyState]
/* this will evaluate to 
type MyStatePayloads = {
    key: "foo";
    value: string;
} | {
    key: "bar";
    value: number;
} | {
    key: "baz";
    value: boolean;
}
*/


// by the way you can skip the `: State` here
set(state, action: PayloadAction<MyStatePayloads >) {
  const { key, value } = action.payload;
  state[key] = value;
},
```

That said, I'd also recommend giving the Redux Style guide a read:
[Model actions as events, not setters.](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/#model-actions-as-events-not-setters)